# how to declare a NSArray with unichars?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I want to create a NSArray like following :

```
NSArray * alphabets = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z',nil];
```

but I will get BAD_ACCESS_ERROR during execution of that.

how can I figure it out and make this line of code working?

regards

Comment: Declare the strings like this: @"a",@"b",...

Comment: I need to use unichars for some reasons what should I do about it? actually I want to store NSArray into a NSDictionary and I want my NSarray or something array filled up with unichars . any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add to `NSArray` only objects. For example,

```
NSArray * alphabets = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c",@"d",@"e",nil];
```

But `'a'` is not an object. When you write `@"a"` compile creates object of type `NSString` and adds it to your `array`.

Answer (score 2):

`'a'` is not valid NSObject, it's primitive type of `char`

to use `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:...]` you need to pass it objects

like this:

```
NSArray * alphabets = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c",@"d",@"e",nil];
```

or use C/C++ notation of array

```
char[] alphabet ....
```